# AC versus DC max limit on connector

Tags: connector

I have a connector that says 250VAC and 10A max while the same connector has 60VDC and 2.5A max.

Why does the current limit differ so much?

Link: [Hawke InstrumEx](https://www.hubbell.com/hawke/en/Products/Electrical-Electronic/Electrical-Connectors/Hazardous-Location/InstrumEx/p/2147033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That difference would be due to arcing during make and break. DC arcs way more than AC.

Here is a practical example for you of the problem at hand: [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY)
[image]

I would have no issues in running 250 VDC and 10 A though it for a one-off and supervised test setup but if you unplug it at that level, you will have a bad time. You sometimes see several DC voltage levels for connectors and relays depending on current since there is less "ompf" behind the breaking forming the arc at lower voltage despite higher current, and vice versa.

Comment: AC arcs tend to self extinguish when the voltage passes through 0V, but DC will maintain that ionized path and keep the arc going.